# salesforce Trailhead challenge topic : use standard controllers

Tags: visualforce, trailhead

I am new to salesforce platform ,i am getting error while solving Trailhead challenge. suggest me how to solve this error.

REF:: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_standard_controllers

CHALLENGE:Using the Contact standard controller, create a Visualforce page which displays a Contact's First Name, Last Name and the Email address of the Contact's Owner.

```
The page must be named 'ContactView'.
It must reference the Contact standard controller.
It should include a bound variable that uses the standard controller to display the first name of the Contact.
It should include a bound variable that uses the standard controller to display the last name of the Contact.
It should include a bound variable that uses the standard controller to display the Contact Owner's email.
```

ERROR:Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
The page does not include the Contact standard controller

My Code:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="Contact" >
    {!$Contact.Last Name}
    {!$Contact.First Name}
    Contact Owner : {!$Contact.Owner.Email}
</apex:page>
```

Thanks and Regards
sainath

Comment: Please include your code used within Visualforce page and also your controller.

Comment: Hi smith<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" Standardcontroller="Contact" >
    {!$Contact.Last Name} {!$Contact.First Name}
    Contact Owner : {!$Contact.Owner.Email}
</apex:page>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be using a Standard Controller for this module.

```
standardController="Contact"
```

Your page should look like the following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">  
    <apex:pageBlock title="Contact Summary">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >

            FirstName: {!Contact.FirstName } <br/>
            LastName: {!Contact.LastName } <br/>
            OwnersEmail: {!Contact.Owner.Email } <br/>       

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>   
</apex:page>
```

Go through the example Salesforce provide within this module for the Account. It is almost identical except using a different object and fields.

Comment: If my response to your question helped please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Remove $ sign from the fields like..{!Contact.FirtsName}